# Text is not detected in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to generate a Json with knockoutJs, but before creating the Json I pass a Base64 image in a Text area, but it is not recognized by Knockout.

```
    document.getElementById('SubmitButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var i = 1; i < initialData.length + 1; i++) {
            var data = arrayOfSignaturePads[i].toDataURL('image/png');
            document.getElementById('signatureField' + i).value = data;
        }

        document.getElementById('submitButton2').click();
    });
```

This code writes the  base 64 in

```
<textarea data-bind='attr :{ id: "signatureField"+id}, value:signature'></textarea>
```

I have this Base64 data in the textarea field:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBO..
```

But I get this Json with the signature attribute in blank

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "department": "Sunset",
    "responsible": "Daniel",
    "signature": "",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "description": "Clean",
        "date": "10/21/2019"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And if I manually write a '#' in the textarea field for example:

```
#data:image/png;base64,iVBO..
```

The base64 is added to the Json!

How can I fix it? :(

Comment: maybe provide a jsfiddle or code snippet with what you have so far :)

Comment: try to use data-bind="text:signature" on the text-area instead, or try with input type text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Knockout, you don't update the value of the element directly. Your code with `document.getElementById('signatureField' + i).value = data;` should be replaced with `viewModelObject.signature(data);` where `viewModelObject` is the name of your view model object.